# Why are Go C types different when they come from different modules?

Tags: go, cgo

In Go, I have a compile error due to incompatible types which I cannot explain. I'm using the `"C"` module. A minimum example consists of the following 2 files:

```
package module

import "C"

type T struct {
    X C.int
}
```

and a main program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sandbox/module"
)

import "C"

func f() *module.T {
    var x C.int = 42
    return &module.T{X: x}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("value: %d", f().X)
}
```

This fails to compile with the message
`./main.go:12: cannot use x (type C.int) as type module.C.int in field value`.

For some reason the compiler thinks that `C.int` is not equal to `module.C.int`.

It must have something to do with the `C` module and the fact that the code is spread across 2 modules because it suddenly works if I switch from `C.int` to plain `int`.

Why does this piece of code not compile? What would be the proper solution to make it compile without squashing all code together in one module?

I'm using the latest Go compiler 1.9.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [Command cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)
>
> [Go references to C](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C)
>
> Cgo translates C types into equivalent unexported Go types. Because
>   the translations are unexported, a Go package should not expose C
>   types in its exported API: a C type used in one Go package is
>   different from the same C type used in another.

You say, "For some reason the compiler thinks that C.int is not equal to module.C.int." As the cgo command documentation explains, unexported Go types in different packages are not equal.

Don't expose C types in an exported API. For example,

`module.go`:

```
package module

type T struct {
    X int
}
```

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sandbox/module"
)

import "C"

func f() *module.T {
    var x C.int = 42
    return &module.T{X: int(x)}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("value: %d\n", f().X)
}
```

Output:

```
value: 42
```